# What to use for embedded arrays?

Tags: admin-on-rest

Is there support for embedded arrays in form? Like list of emails or phone numbers (these entities do not exist as standalone resource so it is impossible to use Reference* fields/inputs). SelectArrayInput looks promising, but it needs to know in advance possible options which is not the case (maybe there is an easy way to modify it to accept any option after hiting an enter button?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently, you'll have to make a [custom input](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#writing-your-own-input-component). If you do, please make it an addon and we'll reference it in the documentation.

Also note that someone started an addon about this: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/pull/697

Comment: I end up with striped version of SelectArrayInput (just removed choices and setFilter) https://gist.github.com/andreysaksonov/7ade1642320c577f8c8ccd52c7284a3a